# Format string date into date object

Tags: date, typescript

I have a date in this format: `December 5th 2017`. How do I convert it to either a timestamp or a date object?

I tried the following but it return NaN:

`let tDate = new Date('December 5th 2017')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a library like moment.js (momentjs.com) to parse custom date formats into Dates. As of version 2.13 it apparently comes with typings out of the box and can therefore be used easily with TypeScript (aureliajsrocks.com/moment-js-now-typescript-compatbile)